# Could a function be applied on a specific set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set A=$\{( n+2) /( 2n+1) :\ n\in N\}
(\mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \Re )$. 
Then I want to apply a function [for example ln() - natural logarithm] on set A that will produce a new set 
B=$\{ln[( n+2) /( 2n+1)] :\ n\in N\}$. 
If it is possible then, should I write it like a composite function? 

What notation should I use to show that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will it be sufficient to write the function as

$f:A\rightarrow B$ such that
$f(x)=ln(x)$ 
?

Comment: Is there another way to show that?

Comment: Well.. Most of the times it will be enough to write down the domain and the range (connected through an arrow) and then write the general equation of the equation that describe the function. Is there any specific detail that you would like to include?

Comment: To show explicitly that we created a new set B, but not a new function f(x).

Comment: How about $B=\{ f(x): x\in A \} $

Comment: Yes, this one will do. Very good point!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a function can be extended to subsets of the domain.
That is called the set extension of the function.
If A is a subset of the domain of a function f,
f(A) or for careful notation, f[A] = { f(x) : x in A }.
The inverse set extension is f$^{-1}$(B) or
f$^{-1}$[B] = { x : f(x) in B }
which is commonly used in the topological definition of continuity.

For your example, B = ln[A].

Comment: Very thoughtful answer! Does it mean if I apply B=ln[A] then the previous set A is A=e^[B]? Does it work for any set A?