# Apply function on two set to create a new (+ process validation: bootstrap iterations)

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, notation, bootstrap-sampling

I am new to algebra and help would be more than welcome to tell me if the process I have built is OK, and if my attempt to apply formula on two sets to create a new one is also OK.

**Context**

I have a database containing species records (e.g. 10 different species, with 100 rows by species ; in columns are quantitative variables). I want to compute Euclidean distances (considering all variables) between randomly sampled 20 row by species, between each species and species *h*. I want to bootstrap this calculation an increasing number of time to assess the effect of iteration augmentation on results linearity (to say: OK, we have reach linearity, results should be OK). The aim is to show a figure like that (1 line color = 1 species Euclidean distance to species *h*):

[image]

**To explain the process, I illustrate it with distance calculation between species [image] and species *h*:**

1. We define sets [image] and [image] as original species records.

[image]

[image]

2. Then we define [image] and [image] as proper subsets of [image] and [image] composed of 20 records randomly sampled in [image] and [image], without replacement, so that probability *P(r)* for records to be selected is:

[image]

[image]

3. Then we define the following function to compute the mean Euclidean distance between all records of [image] and [image]

[image]

With *n* = 20 (variables) and *n'* = 20 (randomly sampled records ; size of [image] and [image]).

4. Then we define set *D*, which contains Euclidean distances between records [image] and [image]:

[image]

5. Finally, we define set *B* containing number of iterations of the whole process, from sampling event (with replacement between each iteration, giving a probability [image] for records to be selected between iterations) to sed *D* computation. The following formula [image] allow computing set *M*:

[image]

[image]

[image]

With *B* = rounded values.

Mainly, I am not pretty sure that I have the *right* to build [image] this way...

**Could you please tell me if it is OK to call functions this way in sets ? And if you spot mistakes in the process ?**

Many thanks for your help !

Comment: @Asaf Karagila, why did you remove 'set' topic ? My question is broadly linked to set construction ; particularly, I need to know if I have the *right* to build them this way...

Comment: Not every question about sets is a question about set theory.

Comment: Yes, off course, I agree ;) - but the lefting topics are less linked to my main questions than the possibility to build set using external sources (particularly with *n''*...)

Comment: Look at questions on the set theory tags, read the description, and then figure out why this is not a suitable tag for this question.

Comment: This question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3426433/could-a-function-be-applied-on-a-specific-set has for topic 'elementary set theory' and even not directly linked to 'theory', its about 'rules' (a bit like mine - I uses this particular topic to build my process) and I think that it is a bit the same case here... (the main point is about set building rules, and the right, or not to build it the way I tried...).

Comment: That was a question about notation. It should have been tagged under [notation]. And it's closed, too, indicating that as far as examples go, that's not a good one.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying ; anyway, do you have any better topic suggestion? (Or do you have an opinion on the way I tried to build the sets in this process ?). Thx for your help & information